# How to plot multiple 3d lines with plotly express?

Tags: python, plotly

I would like to have more than just one 3d line in my graph to be able to compare the data unfortunately this `.add_` methods are not present for all kinds of plots.

```
fig = px.line_3d(sample, x='Time', y='y' ,z='intensity')
# fig.add_line_3d(sample2, x='Time', y='y' ,z='intensity')
fig
```

Can I extract the traces from a figure and then plot them all together somehow?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Plotly Express, you can create multiple lines with a single call, so long as your data is in a ["tidy" format](https://www.jeannicholashould.com/tidy-data-in-python.html). You can use the `color` attribute to split your lines and color them differently, like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    X=[0,1,2,3, 1,2,3,4], 
    Y=[0,2,3,1, 1,3,4,2], 
    Z=[0,3,1,2, 1,4,2,3],
    color=["a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b"]
))

import plotly.express as px

fig = px.line_3d(df, x='X', y='Y', z='Z', color="color")
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: What if some lines need the same color but need to be split? (Without doing an explicit for-loop.)